# When to use the MVC4 Web-API vs a traditional HTTP web-service?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I noticed when the MVC4 beta was announced, it includes a new "**Web-API**".
[(MVC 4 announcement)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4)

In what circumstances should I use this Web-API instead of a normal HTTP/WCF Web-service?
What problem is it trying to solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Web API allows you to very easily expose an API of some existing web site (or build a new one) using standard RESTful techniques. Achieving the same goal with WCF would be a little more challenging but could be done. Scott Gu wrote a [nice overview](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx) of the Web API.

Comment: I've been thinking that a Controller could easily be used to implementing a RESTful service, and you're right. It would be easier than doing it in WCF. Thanks!